# PHP copy() doesn't work for random URLS which redirect to files

Tags: php, copy

trying to copy() .MP3 file from remote url but it always fails.

```
$link = str_replace(' ','%20','http://mp3hungama.com/music/download.php?song_id=80522');
if (!copy($link,'/home2/muser/tmp/newname.mp3')) {
            echo 'copy failed !';
        }
```

$link url redirects to `http://mp3hungama.com/music/audio//Indian%20Movies/Indian%20Movies%20Hindi%20Mp3%20Songs/Singh%20Is%20Bling%20(2015)/songs/Cinema%20Dekhe%20Mamma%20@%20Mp3HunGama.Com.mp3`
same code works for others random urls like `www.example.com/download.php?id=2332`. what's the specifically problem here or any other way to do this job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code and I also couldn't download the file, then, I've used [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) an it work as expected:

```
$local_file = "/home2/muser/tmp/newname.mp3";//This is the file where we save the information
$remote_file = "http://mp3hungama.com/music/download.php?song_id=80522"; //Here is the file we are downloading

$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen ($local_file, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($remote_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

---

**NOTE:**

Make sure `/home2/muser/tmp/` has write permissions.

---

**TIP:**

In the future, if you need to encode/decode a url, use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) or [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) instead of `str_replace`

Comment: awesome, worked fine, could you please brief why curl can do this and why not php `copy()` ? thank you for your solution.

Comment: It may be due to the arguments or the url redirection, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://mp3hungama.com/music/download.php?song_id=80522)

already redirects to second link. So it's working already.